# How to compare two string containing a decimal value?

Tags: c++, string, overflow, precision, stringstream

Here is what I'm doing:

`if (oss.str() != sValue)`

I can have for example:

`2000000000.000` and `2000000000.0`.

That's the same value, but not the same string. I need to compare it in string because I'm trying to catch an eventual overflow of `sValue`.

In this case I could do :

`oss << std::setprecison(1) << std::fixed << value;`

But the problem will be the same if I have:

`2000000000.1` and `2000000000.123`

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is removing all the trailing 0's enough, or do you need something like 1000.0 == 999.99 ?

Comment: @grasGendarme No, I need to know if the values are the same. (exactly the same) In your case the condition must return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working answer :

```
size_t            i;

  i = sValue.find('.');  // find the point
  if (i < sValue.size())  // if there is one, then ...
    {
      i = sValue.size() - i - 1; // find the number of decimal
      oss << std::setprecision(i) << std::fixed << value;  // apply the precision
    }
  else // otherwise, it's neither a float neither a double
    oss << std::setprecision(0) << std::fixed << value; // no need of precision
  if (oss.str() != sValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from the decimal position and do two sets of comparisons, parsing and comparing one digit at each iteration, going to the opposite ends.

Comment: You can take the numbers before the decimal point and make the two the same length by pre-pending 0s to the shorter one. After the decimal point, you can append 0s to the shorter one. Each follow by a string comparison. And a sign check.

Comment: And yes, it's not a one- or two-liner (if I was the one implementing this).

Answer (score 0):

You can use strncmp() function from

```
   int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

with the c_str() methods on the std::string and n = min( s1.length(), s2.length() );

Using integer comparisons is easier with boost

```
boost::lexical_cast<int>(s1) == boost::lexical_cast<int>(s2)
```

for std::string s1, s2 does the job.

Comment: Then simple answer is to convert to numeric type and check the equality. Hopefully you're comparing integers than floating point.

Comment: @grasGendarme There won't be 0's at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Arcturus `boost::lexical_cast<int>` won't work if I'm checking the overflow for an int.

Comment: @Arcturus `min` doesn't work as you say : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/?kw=min

Comment: @Elfayer mine is a a best-effort implementation. Clearly choosing ease of use. But you want a string based solution seems like.. and if so you havea sparse problem description.